# C ++ program for the area under a curve. (the upper limit)?

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is what I have for the upper limit. My value for n is 5. But I think I messed up somewhere because when I calculate it out by hand its not the same value. Does anyone know whats wrong with my program?

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<math.h> 
#include<iomanip> 
#include<fstream> 

using namespace std; 
double f(double x) 
{ 
    return (0.6*pow(x,2)) +4; 
} 
int main ( ) 
{ 

    double a, b, delx, x, area; 
    int n; 

    cout << "Welcome. To begin, please enter a value for 'a' followed by a value for 'b'. \n"; 
    cin>>a>>b; 
    cout << "You have entered a = " << a<<" & b = " <<b <<". Now, input an n value \n"; 
    cin >>n; 

    delx = (b-a)/n; 
    area = 0; 

    for (int i=0;i<=n;i++) 
    { 
        area = area + f(a+i*delx)*delx; 
    } 

    cout << "The area under the curve of f(x) = 0.6x^2 + 4 is "; 
    cout << setprecision(5) << area; 


    system ("pause"); 

}
```

Comment: What values do you use for a and b, what result do you get from your code, and what result do you get with a pencil?

Comment: At a quick glance, your program looks fine. Note that it's only _approximating_ the integral, though; if you try entering a much larger value of n, do you get closer to the right answer?

Comment: I believe you want `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)` (rather than `i <= n`) there, otherwise you're adding up `n + 1` approximating rectangles but dividing by `n` in `delx`. This particular function could easily be integrated symbolically, though.

Comment: the function I use is 0.6^2x+4. I get 32.9 for my code and pencil I get 45

Comment: But what are your `a` and `b` values  in that case, @mattawampmann? (Or `x0` and `x1`, I'd say)

Comment: Don't you mean 0.6 * x^2 + 4? In your example, what do you set as the upper and lower limits?

Comment: yes sorry typo. I mean 0.6 * x^2 + 4. the lower lim is 0 and the upper is 5

Comment: @Wintermute has already pointed out your error. With only five intervals, the one-off error is pretty big

Comment: For low values of `n`, the approximation is bound to be bad either way (although the off-by-one certainly doesn't help). For high values of `n`, I get reasonable results, so I suspect a low choice of `n` is the remaining issue.

Comment: You are not employing any correct numerical method for integration: Look at either trapezoidal or Simpson method.

Comment: OP is using the rectangle rule. It doesn't converge particularly quickly when compared to the trapezoidal or Simpson's rule, but calling it incorrect is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @Wintermute: I agree to a certain extent.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    double a=0, b=5; //a: lower limit, b: upper limit of integration
    int n=20; //the number of intervals
    double dx = (b-a)/n; //step size
    double area = 0; //our goal to find

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) 
    { 
        //using trapezoidal method
        //the area of a trapezoid is (lower base + upper base)*height/2
        //f(a+i*dx): upper base, f(a+(i+1)*dx): lower base
        //dx: height of the trapezoid
        area = area + (f(a+i*dx)+f(a+(i+1)*dx))*dx/2.0; 
    } 

    std::cout<<area;

}
```

Although your approach is not incorrect(but not ideal) trapezoidal method will converge faster. In your approach, you can set n (the number of intervals) to a higher number than trapezoidal to obtain the similar level of accuracy.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14559596)

Comment: Question is: "Does anyone know whats wrong with my program?", further comment is: " the function I use is 0.6^2x+4. I get 32.9 for my code and pencil I get 45". This is indeed then a solution.

Comment: It would be helpful to add more context/explanation around this (rather than just having a code-only answer).

Comment: At the time of my review this was a code-only answer, comment at least on what your code does.